# Run one of two different SELECT queries based on condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my problem, in a nutshell.

I have one table.  It contains messages I want to display based on the values of a start time column and an end time column relative to server time($time).

the first row of the table is a default message that I want to display if there are NO messages with a start time <= $time and end time > $time.

I can pull the most recent message and display it no problem using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE start <= $time and end > $time;
```

I can't figure out how to get my default to display if no other rows match the above criteria.

I tried this:

```
 $sql="SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table WHERE start <= $time AND end > $time) > 0
    THEN (SELECT * FROM $table WHERE start <= $time AND end > $time)
    ELSE (SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = 1)
    END";
```

but it returns this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object.
```

Not sure what to do.  Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: since you are getting some PHP error message could you maybe show your PHP code as well?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't make two queries. Do it in a single query:

```
SELECT *
FROM $table
WHERE (start <= $time and end > $time)
OR id = 1
ORDER BY id ASC
```

This will always return row with id = 1 and will also return any additional rows that match. Assuming 1 is your lowest id value, this would always return your default values in first row.

I will say though that this is generally a bit of a programming anti-pattern.  I would think that your default values should be defined on code config somewhere rather than mixed in with you legitimate data rows.  You are going to have to do weird things like the this query to work around your desire to have you defaults stored in such a manner.

Comment: Hi Mike.  I found your solution worked best for what I am trying to do.  I agree what I'm doing is a little counter-intuitive.  Normally I would store the default state as a variable unrelated to my db content and pull that in an IF / Else statement.  I need to have the default state be something that can me modified through a form, so it has to be db driven as well.  I changed your code so it ordered by DESC and used LIMIT to just display the top result.  This worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score -1):

Do it in PHP instead of SQL.  I don't know your system, but for mysqli:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE start <= $time and end > $time;";

$res = mysqli_query($dbobj,$sql);

if (!$res || !$res->num_rows) {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = 1;";
}
$res = mysqli_query($dbobj,$sql);
```

Comment: Great!  Note that I just edited the mysqli_query to be correct (showing the $connection param).